# Can DataMapper properties appear in multiple composite indexes?

Tags: ruby, indexing, datamapper, composite-index

I found that this issue had been discussed in [Ticket #58](http://datamapper.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20609/tickets/58-specify-table-indexes-in-model) of DataMapper, apparently way back in 2007, but I can't find how to do it in the latest version (dm-core-0.10.2). I want to define two composite indexes, each of which are partially based on a certain property. I was hoping I could do this...

```
class Stat
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,            Serial,
  property :collected_on,  Integer #yyyyMMddhhmm
  property :measure,       Integer
  property :dimension_one, Integer
  property :dimension_two, Integer
  property :source_id,     Integer
  index [:collected_on, :dimension_one, :dimension_two]
  index [:source_id, :collected_on]
end
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
class Stat
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,            Serial,
  property :collected_on,  Integer, :index => [ :index_one, :index_two ]
  property :measure,       Integer
  property :dimension_one, Integer, :index => :index_one
  property :dimension_two, Integer, :index => :index_one
  property :source_id,     Integer, :index => :index_two
end
```

Of course you can make the indexes anything you like. The indexes can be an `Array`, or a `Symbol` as shown above, or even just `true` if you want to put the property in an index by itself and you don't care what the index is called.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this could work in the specific example I gave as long as I moved the :source_id property above the :collected_on property, so that :index_two will be [:source_id,:collected_on] instead of [:collected_on,:source_id]... but what would you do if you need an index on both orders?

Comment: For unique indices use `:unique_index =>` in place of `:index =>`. The well hidden documentation can be found [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Property).